# Creating single-cycle permutations

Tags: permutation, pseudo-random-permutation

There was this one time I came up with a small permutation that had a block size of 16 bits. This was small enough to compute every mapping. I then iterated the mapping starting with zero to see how many iterations it would take to return to zero. The number was less than half of $2^{16}$.

For whatever reason, let's say a person needs a pseudorandom permutation that has only one cycle. Perhaps they need to make a single-cycle S-box or they want to use the permutation to create a non-linear tweak to the plaintext input of a block cipher (each block's tweak is the result of successive iterations instead of increments of one). First thing that comes to my mind is a full-period LCG, but when I tried this for making an S-box ($f(x) = (37 \cdot x + 11) \mbox{ mod } 256$), the results seemed rather orderly. This wouldn't matter for a tweak for plaintext blocks, but it seems desirable to simply not have that property of orderliness. So, what are some way of generating/constructing single-cycle permutations?

Answer (score 7):

The obvious way to construct such a pseudorandom single-cycle permutation is to take a pseudorandom permutation $P$ (which need not be single-cycle), a simple fixed single-cycle permutation $Inc$ (e.g. just increment the value by 1), and construct:

$$S = P^{-1} \ \circ Inc \ \circ P $$

That is, to evaluate $S(x)$, you first apply the permutation $P$ to $x$, then the permutation $Inc$, and then the permutation $P^{-1}$, which is the inverse of the permutation $P$.

Things that should be obvious:

- $S$ is a single cycle permutation
- Every single cycle permutation can be expressed this way with an appropriate choice of $P$
- (Less obvious) if $P$ is selected uniformly over all permutations, then $S$ is selected uniformly over all single-cycle permutations.

Comment: $(f\circ g)(x)$ usually means $f(g(x))$, *i.e.*, $g$ is applied first. ;)

Comment: @fkraiem: ordering *really* doesn't matter here, but ok, I fixed it...

Comment: [Reference](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00145-001-0008-5).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a single cycle s box and want to construct it by drawing a uniformly random single cycle permutation this can be done directly:

1. Create a set P of numbers 2..N
2. Set Idx=1
3. Draw a random member M from P assign it to the index Idx
4. Remove the member from P
5. Set Idx=M
6. If P is nonempty repeat from step 3.
7. Assign 1 to the last spot at Idx.

You can represent P with an Array and a size counter, in order to remove an element you copy the last element to it's position and reduce size. This allows all steps to be $O(1)$ and the total runtime $O(n)$

If you want a large single cycle permutation (too big to keep materialized in full) poncho gave a fair solution which relies on a pseudo random permutation.